# How could 'Complete and Easy Bidirectional Type Checking' handle invariant parameters on type constructors

Tags: type-theory, type-checking, type-inference

The paper [Complete and Easy Bidirectional Typechecking for Higher-Rank Polymorphism](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~nk480/bidir.pdf) provides examples for checking if one function type is a subtype of another, which I think demonstrates checking constructors with parameters which are covariant or contravariant.

I can not see an example of the subtype rule for type constructors with type parameters which are **invariant**.

For example consider some impure, mutable stack type:

```
type Stack : * -> *

push : forall a. Stack a -> a -> ()
pop : forall a. Stack a -> a
```

The type parameter on `Stack` represents a type that can be inputted and outputted from the stack, which makes it neither covariant nor contravariant.

To implement the subtyping rule for two `Stack` types could I simply apply the subtyping rule twice? Something like:

```
C1 |- a <: b -| C2    C2 |- b <: a -| C3
----------------------------------------
     C1 |- Stack a <: Stack b -| C3
```

Comment: Your `Stack` type is actually covariant. You want an example that either has mutable/IO operations in its type or contains both data and codata.